# Why is String created from Char Array not interned?

Tags: java

Why is the String created from char array not interned?

```
jshell> var a = "Hello"
a ==> "Hello"

jshell> var b = "Hello"
b ==> "Hello"

jshell> a == b
$67 ==> true

jshell> char[] c = {'H','e','l','l','o'}
c ==> char[5] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }

jshell> var d = String.copyValueOf(c)
d ==> "Hello"

jshell> a == d
$70 ==> false
```

Comment: Seems `d` is not created in the String pool.

Comment: Why should it? Does the documentation of `String#copyValueOf` say so? Only String literals are interned (quotation marks). I am confused why you think it should come out of the pool, what made you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `String` iterals are only interned by default.

[`String::copyValueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf(char%5B%5D)) internally returns new `String` :

```
public static String copyValueOf(char[] var0) {
    return new String(var0);
}
```

so you would have to call `intern` on your String that is returned from this method and this will return a reference to this String in the String pool.

Comment: Thanks @michalk. Are these strings not created in String pool? What is the reason behind not interning in these scenarios?

Comment: I think that it is the question for creators of this String API. String pool is just an memory optimization which prevents from creating more String iterals in the memory. Since you are the consumer of this API it is up to you if you want to intern a String created from char array or not.

Comment: What would be the reason for "interning it in these scenarios"? The question does not make much sense. Interned strings are for literal constants, so not sure why you feel like a normal string should be handled in that way.

Comment: Hi @PavelHoral, as far as I understand , string interning was implemented for literals for optimizing the memory space. So I wanted to understand why the same approach is not taken here. I am not questioning the approach , just wanted to understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: You are creating string from a char array and that is nothing special from the language point of view. String literals are on the other hand (immutable) constant "expressions" (quotes as that word is not used correctly here afaik) in the source code.